# Нужно ли вопрос в этом предложении отделять знаком (:/,), заключать в кавычки, ставить знак вопроса в конце предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

"[название книги]" - это своеобразный ответ на вопрос "есть ли жизнь среди звезд?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны два варианта пунктуационного оформления этого предложения:

A) ***"[Название книги]" - это своеобразный ответ на вопрос, есть ли жизнь среди звезд.***

Б) ***"[Название книги]" - это своеобразный ответ на вопрос: есть ли жизнь среди звезд?***

Сходство этих вариантов в том, что и в том и в другом случае **кавычки не ставятся**, потому что никакой прямой речи здесь нет.

Но какой же из них выбрать?

**Вариант А:** в предложении нет ярко выраженных пауз, вопросительная интонация отсутствует. Тут мы имеем дело с обычным сложноподчиненным предложением с косвенным вопросом.

http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_2.htm#ppp_5

> Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: Я прервал речь Савельича **вопросом**, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н. О.).

**Вариант Б:** делается акцент и понижение тона на слове «вопрос», далее следует длительная пауза, а затем идёт прямой вопрос с явной вопросительной интонацией.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

> Перед прямым вопросом, включенным в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения, ставится двоеточие: Спрашивается теперь: что же делало наше общество в последние 20 — 30 лет? (Добр.); Одного только я не понимаю: как она могла тебя укусить? (Ч.); До сих пор удивительным и неразгаданным остаётся: кто же в эту роковую ночь дивизионную школу снял с караула?’(Фурм.); Я прошёл к калитке по мокрой траве, испытывая тревогу: кто же рассмотрит первый трактор в таком непроглядном тумане? (Перв.)

Comment: Игорь, очень хороший ответ, мне вообще нравится, как выработаете. Но всё-таки у меня есть замечание. Почему вы не стали рассматривать заданный вариант с кавычками, разве его нельзя  оставить?  Ваши вариант  очень хороши сами по себе, но насколько они вписываются в предложение с тире между подлежащим и сказуемым? В первую очередь это касается варианта с двоеточием, ведь нам приходится делить предложение на три части двумя  увеличенными паузами. Пожалуйста, скажите, что вы об этом думаете.

Comment: Отвечаю в меру своих знаний. Каждый ваш комментарий необычайно точен и правилен. Вот к какому уровню я буду стремиться. Однако у меня после них отбивается желание отвечать, ибо мне знаний для полноценного корректного ответа просто недостаточно..( Спасибо Вам за замечание!!! Действительно, вариант с кавычками будет очень релевантным.

Comment: Хотя я ответил, но сейчас уже не уверен. Если обрамлять кавычками, то это будет похоже на цитату. А это разве цитата? Извините заранее за мою возможную глупость.

Comment: Вот и не торопитесь с решениями.  Я полагаю, что  существует определенная формулировка вопроса, вот мы ее и цитируем по образцу прямой речи в роли  несогласованного определения. Это вполне корректная запись. Конечно, ваши варианты  без кавычек смотрятся намного лучше, но структура предложения может накладывать определенные ограничения. Ваша вариант с запятой, как мне кажется, самый удачный, так как там не требуется вторая пауза.

Comment: И еще.  Честно говоря, становится не по себе от  того, что у кого-то "отбивается желание отвечать". Кажется, что твое присутствие на форуме лишнее, мешает другим. А  вы очень быстро обучаетесь, и особенно ценно то, что анализируете  интонацию предложения.  Таких участников здесь мало.  Я бы не стала делать вам замечание,  долго сомневалась, но очень уж хотелось, чтобы ваши знания стали еще лучше.